# Common footer is not display in second.html

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi I have one separate page for footer as footer.html & I want to use that in all other html files,But it is displays only in index.html (Main file or starting page of my application in phonegap project), And in other pages it is not display. My footer.html is as:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="docsdemos-style-override.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>


  </head> 

    <body>

<div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="ui-btn-active" href="#page1" data-theme="a"
        data-icon="home"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="#page3" data-theme="a" data-icon="plus"> Feeds </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#page7" data-theme="a" data-icon="grid"> Gadgets
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#page9" data-theme="a" data-icon="info"> Profile
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#page14" data-theme="a" data-icon="gear">
        Settings </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
   </body>
    </html>
```

My index.html is as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery Mobile: Demos and Documentation</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="docsdemos-style-override.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
<!-- Uncomment following line to access PhoneGap APIs (not necessary to use PhoneGap to package web app) -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.1.js"></script>-->


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui)
    {
        $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=footer]").load("footer.html", function()
        {
                $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=navbar]").navbar();
        });
    });
 </script>

 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div data-role="page" id="jqm-home" class="type-home">
<div data-role="content">


    <div class="content-secondary"> 


        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c"      data-dividertheme="f">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li>
            <li><a href="second.html" >First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Supported platforms</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!--/content-primary-->   

</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed">
</div>  

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And second.html is as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery Mobile: Demos and Documentation</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="docsdemos-style-override.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
<!-- Uncomment following line to access PhoneGap APIs (not necessary to use PhoneGap to     package web app) -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.1.js"></script>-->


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui)
    {
        $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=footer]").load("footer.html", function()
        {
                $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=navbar]").navbar();
        });
    });
 </script>

</head> 
 <body> 
 <div data-role="page" id="jqm-home" class="type-home">
<div data-role="content">


    <div class="content-secondary"> 


        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li data-role="list-divider">2nd page</li>
            <li><a href="index.html" >Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Supported platforms</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!--/content-primary-->   

</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed">
</div>  

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here in second.html footer is not display. And one more query when I click on First list control goes to second.html file but sometimes it does not go and sometimes only black screen appears. Why is it so?

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it over headheck  to load all `js`,`cs` for only `footer` and you can make on function which will return you the html like `"<div data-role="navbar" ></div>"`  then append to  `data-role="footer"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default jQuery Mobile uses ajax to load pages. So in your case when you refer to `second.html` it will load the `page` div via ajax and inject in current DOM so any javascript defined on that html page wont execute.

Try this in your index.html

```
<li><a href="second.html" rel="external">First</a></li>
```

or

```
<li><a href="second.html" data-ajax="false">First</a></li>
```

This way it will reload the whole `second.html` page

Answer (score 0):

There will be some HTML validation problem in second.html file code thats why its not showing the footer